# find max average from a list python

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
input= [
   ["Pakistan", 23],
   ["Pakistan", 127],
   ["India", 3],
   ["India", 71],
   ["Australia", 31],
   ["India", 22],
   ["Pakistan", 81]
]
```

Now i want to filter out only that key value who has highest average . Like in this case output should be "Pakistan":

```
out = "Pakistan"
```

Can anybody help

Comment: first i am trying to separate key and value so that i can take a average

Comment: Please post the code that you have written to solve this problem, and we will help you find a solution.

Comment: solution is already given check bellow

Comment: I would try using a numpy array and setting axis the axis kwarg in numpy.max

Comment: same i was trying .. but solution is already here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

l =  [
["Pakistan", 23],
["Pakistan", 127],
["India", 3],
["India", 71],
["Australia", 31],
["India", 22],
["Pakistan", 81]
]

pd.DataFrame(l).groupby([0]).mean().idxmax().values[0]
```

Output:

```
'Pakistan'
```

Comment: @Scott With all due respect, why didn't you wait for the OP to post some sample code first? Isn't it our responsibility to first try and understand the OP's approach, then try and guide him / her towards a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Another version (with stdlib only):

```
from __future__ import division
import collections

input= [
   ["Pakistan", 23],
   ["Pakistan", 127],
   ["India", 3],
   ["India", 71],
   ["Australia", 31],
   ["India", 22],
   ["Pakistan", 81]
]


t = collections.defaultdict(list)

for c,n in input:
    t[c].append(n)


max(t, key=lambda c: sum(t[c]) / len(t[c]))
'Pakistan'
```

Comment: In Python 2 integer division can be an issue here: `sum(t[c]) / len(t[c])`, and in Python 3, you could use `statistics.mean`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one another variation of implementation.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import operator

input= [
   ["Pakistan", 23],
   ["Pakistan", 127],
   ["India", 3],
   ["India", 71],
   ["Australia", 31],
   ["India", 22],
   ["Pakistan", 81]
]
cv_dict=defaultdict(list)

for key, score in input:
    cv_dict[key].append(score)

for k,v in cv_dict.items():
        cv_dict[k]=sum(v)/len(v)

max(cv_dict, key=cv_dict.get)
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Why don't try in-built `max` method , without importing any heavy external module or making it too complex?

```
input= [
   ["Pakistan", 23],
   ["Pakistan", 127],
   ["India", 3],
   ["India", 71],
   ["Australia", 31],
   ["India", 22],
   ["Pakistan", 81]
]

track={}
for i in input:
    if i[0] not in track:
        track[i[0]]=[i[1]]
    else:
        track[i[0]].append(i[1])

print(max([(sum(j)/len(j),i) for i,j in track.items()]))
```

output:

```
(77.0, 'Pakistan')
```

Comment: The question asks for *key value who has highest average*, not key value with highest number.

Comment: @GaneshTata Thanks for pointing out, i have updated the solution.